A parent who may be a poet dies and children(?) go through a manuscript
In this movie (possibly international*), an old parent (probably a father) dies (or is dying) and somewhat estranged children (grown adults) come to deal with the situation.  The parent had been a poet or something, but had succumbed to dementia. 
One of the adult children finds a stack of what appear to be incoherent writings hand-written haphazardly across the pages and begins to read and oraganize them.  It tells the story of the parent's life, and the kid has hte pages arranged as an array on the floor to read the story.
In one scene, (if this is the same movie) the writer recounts seeing his own abusive father commit suicide as a young boy, which involves a very beautiful stylized slow-motion gunshot tipping backwards the chair in which the father seated. 
*By "possibly international", I meant that there is a low (but non-zero) likelihood that it may have been a European movie (non-US). I am fairly certain I saw this movie on an intercontinental flight, but I cannot confirm that it is an English-language film.  The actors in my memory are most definitely white though.

I'm guessing you're talking about the Laura Linney and Phillip Seymour Hoffman film, The Savages:

After drifting apart emotionally over the years, two single siblings — Wendy (Linney) and Jon (Hoffman) — band together to care for their estranged, elderly father, Lenny (Philip Bosco), who is rapidly slipping into dementia. Wendy and Jon first travel to Sun City, Arizona to attend the funeral of their father's girlfriend of 20 years. When they arrive, they are told that their father signed a non-marriage agreement and will not have rights to any of her property. They then move him to a nursing home in Buffalo, where Jon is a theater professor working on a book about Bertolt Brecht. Wendy, who is an aspiring, but unsuccessful, playwright, moves from New York City to help establish their father in Buffalo.

I can't line up all of your connections but the basic premise is very similar. Some possible connections... both kids are in the arts, Wendy is a playwright, which is similar to poet.
I haven't seen it myself, though, so I may be incorrect.

I have seen it, but don't remember pages being arranged (though TBH I don't remember much). That part sounds more like Proof, which already came up today.
